# Enumerate sentences in python

Tags: python, string, enumerate

I have a tuple of strings that consists of two sentences

```
a = ('What', 'happened', 'then', '?', 'What', 'would', 'you', 'like', 'to', 'drink','?')
```

I tried this

```
for i,j in enumerate(a):
print i,j
```

which gives

```
0 What
1 happened
2 then
3 ?
4 What
5 would
6 you
7 like
8 to
9 drink
10 ?
```

whereas what I need is this

```
0 What
1 happened
2 then
3 ?
0 What
1 would
2 you
3 like
4 to
5 drink
6?
```

Comment: How would I know were the first line finishes in the tuple ? Is question mark a separator ?

Comment: You have a tuple of strings in your example. This is different from what you state in the description, "A string of two sentences"

Comment: @ Tanveer Alam: yes, that's correct, '?' is a separator but it can also be any other punctuation mark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest would be to manually increase `i` instead of relying on `enumerate` and reset the counter on the character `?`, `.` or `!`.

```
i = 0
for word in sentence:
    print i, word

    if word in ('.', '?', '!'):
        i = 0
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: This is a nice and simple and yet very effective solution! I like other suggestions as well but I agree with @UlfR that this one is the least complicated.

Comment: any idea how this would look like in a `shell` script or `awk`?

Answer (score 1):

Overly complicated maybe. The solution of @JeromeJ is cleaner I think. But:

```
a=('What', 'happened', 'then', '?', 'What', 'would', 'you', 'like', 'to', 'drink','?')
start = 0
try: end = a.index('?', start)+1
except: end = 0

while a[start:end]:
    for i,j in enumerate(a[start:end]):
        print i,j
    start = end
    try: end = a.index('?', start)+1
    except: end = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One more:

```
from itertools import chain

for n,c in chain(enumerate(a[:a.index('?')+1]), enumerate(a[a.index('?')+1:])):
    print "{} {}".format(n,i)
   ....:
0 What
1 happened
2 then
3 ?
0 What
1 would
2 you
3 like
4 to
5 drink
6 ?
```